# Square both sides of an expression and finding function changes derivative of function?

Tags: functions, derivatives

While solving many questions I found that the author square both side of an expression and then find the answer but many times he mentions that **squaring both side** may result in **extra solution**.
For example, consider the given expression :
$$ \begin{align} \ x \sqrt {1+y } + y\sqrt {1+x} = 0 \end{align}$$
**To prove** :
$$ \begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\end{align}$$

He did this :
$$ \begin{align} \ x \sqrt {1+y } =-  y\sqrt {1+x} = 0 \end{align}$$
Then he squared both sides and solved the expression to this :
$$ \begin{align} y=-\frac{x}{1+x}\end{align}$$

And then differentiated which resulted in :
$$ \begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\end{align}$$

My doubt is it may change function range as well like consider
$$ \begin{align}x = -2\end{align}$$
$$ \begin{align}x^2 = 4\end{align}$$
$$ \begin{align}x= \pm2\end{align}$$
Though this function is **not differentiable** at x = 2 or -2 but function is changed this is what I want to say. Consider the graph : [image: Graph]

We have got the extra solution

Comment: Did the author really write $x\sqrt{1 + y} = -y\sqrt{1 + x} \color{red}{= 0}$?

Comment: Yes! It is written equal to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine if the solution found is extraneous, you could substitute it back into the original equation to see if a contradiction is derived. However, let's try to do a little groundwork, first, to see what can be said about a function $f(x)$ such that $y=f(x)$ satisfies the equation $$x\sqrt{1+y}+y\sqrt{1+x}=0\tag{1}$$ for all $x.$

Assuming we're dealing with real numbers, it's immediately clear that $x\ge-1$ and $y\ge-1$ are necessary conditions for $(1)$ to be true. In other words, whatever the function $f(x)$ is, its domain and range must be subsets of $[-1,\infty).$

If we try $x=-1$ in $(1),$ we obtain $-\sqrt{1+y}=0,$ from which we conclude that $y=-1.$ Hence, whatever the function $f(x)$ is, we know that if $f(-1)$ is defined, then $f(-1)=-1.$

Let's check to see if the proposed solution--that is, $$f(x)=-\frac{x}{1+x}$$ for some set of values for $x$--can satisfy either or both of these conditions. Right away, it should be clear that $f(-1)$ is not defined. That's not a big deal, though. If $f(x)=-\frac{x}{1+x}$ is a function $(-1,\infty)\to(-1,\infty)$ satisfying $(1),$ then we can further say that the function $g:[-1,\infty)\to[-1,\infty)$ given by $$g(x)=\begin{cases}f(x) & x>-1\\-1 & x=-1\end{cases}$$ is also a solution. It just happens to not be continuous at $x=-1,$ so isn't differentiable there, either.

Indeed, examining the graph of $f(x)=-\frac{x}{1+x},$ we find that $f(x)>-1$ precisely when $x>-1,$ so it looks promising! All that remains is to check whether $f(x)$ actually makes sense in $(1)$ by substituting (now that we've verified that we even *can* substitute it safely). That is, all that remains is to verify that $$x\sqrt{1-\frac{x}{1+x}}-\frac{x}{1+x}\sqrt{1+x}=0,$$ which I leave to you. (It's pretty straightforward.)

Comment: So, we should verify before differentiating?

Comment: Not necessarily. It's just important when squaring both sides to verify (at some point) that any solution so obtained is *truly* a solution, and isn't extraneous.